# Hyperlinks does not work in read-only text field in acrobat

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I have a pdf fillable form where I am allowing the user to enter additional remarks/comments in a text area.
The issue is that some want to enter hyperlink in the text area, which works fine until the text-area is active. When the form is saved, all fields are made read-only and the hyper-link is not clickable. I tried flattening the page, but even then the link is not clickable.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here.

1. You can add hyperlinks to text field and have them remain functional if the field is set to allow for Rich Text. If the field doesn't allow rich text, any hyperlinks entered will revert back to plain text when the field is exited.
2. Read-only fields are ignored by the mouse. I'd need to understand more about how the PDF is created and what the rest of your code does to recommend a work around.

Comment: The PDF is a form, although there are fields that are being toggled using javascript.  My text area allows rich text and allows a website link to be added. It is when the form is submitted and the fields are made read-only, that the link is not clickable.

Comment: Is there a reason the fields need to be read-only after submitting?

Comment: Yes, the read-only version will be circulated to other external users.

Comment: Ok - If that's the case, there's no solution that's going to work using any kind of scripting in the PDF. You'll need to post-process the PDF after it's submitted to the server. With a decent PDF library, you can located the field that have links and essentially convert the field appearance into page content but in a way that is more sophisticated than flattening and retain the links.